# How to prevent files upload on VS Code with SFTP?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp, vscode-remote

My team keeps uploading `.vscode` folder with `sftp.json` file to our projects, creating a security flaw.
We all use SFTP plugin, which helps us a lot!

There is a config or a file where we can edit to prevent a file upload?

Comment: add a feature request at the sftp extension repo, but how to force all users to have the same setting, you have to put the setting in `.vscode` folder

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called .vscode in your upload folder.  This will prevent the sftp plugin from creating a folder, called .vscode, on the remote site.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the `sftp.json` file the following lines:

```
"ignore": [
    ".vscode/**",
    "YourAnyOtherFolder/**"
]
```